# How to set a maximum date using spring boot in mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Here is my document:

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Document("Template_Schema")
public class TemplateSchema {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private ZonedDateTime activeFrom;
    private ZonedDateTime activeTo;
}
```

I want to set a maximum date in `activeTO` field and save it to mongo using a repository.
I've already tried this:

```
TemplateSchema schema = new TemplateSchema(); 
Instant maxInstant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.MAX_VALUE);
schema.setActiveTo(maxInstant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
templateSchemaRepository.save(schema);
```

This piece of code saves the data. But the date is invalid.
What is the solution to set a maximum date?

Comment: what about `Instant.MAX`

Comment: I have also tried `schema.setActiveTo(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.MAX,ZoneOffset.UTC));` throws error  `java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for EpochDay (valid values -365243219162 - 365241780471): 365241780837`